# Power BI Cumulative sum of accounting

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've created a DAX measure to do the cumulative sum of a specific column ([total_materials] -measure).

Base I have:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLmcX.png)

Once inserting the DAX measure into that table, the result should be:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvU5m.png)

See the cumulative of values at the column are correct! This Is what I really need.
The problem happens when a value repeats in the next line.
The real return of my formula:

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udNaz.png)

Could you help me?

My formula in DAX:

```
Acumulado Oficial =

VAR vQtdMaterial = [total_materiais]
VAR vAcumulado =
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK([total_materiais])),
    CALCULATE(
        [total_materiais],
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(f_kssk_atr_objt_classe[d_klah_classe.CLASS_classe]),
            [total_materiais] >= vQtdMaterial
        )
    )
)
RETURN
IF(
    ISINSCOPE(f_kssk_atr_objt_classe[d_klah_classe.CLASS_classe]),
        vAcumulado,
        vQtdMaterial
)
```

Treatment of the anomaly in the DAX measure

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing a running sum is to have a Calendar table and then do something like this:

```
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('FactTable'[NumericColumn]),
        FILTER(ALL('DimDate'),
           DimDate[Date]<=MAX(DimDate[Date])
        )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can view my example data]

```
    Cumulative Total =
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Column1] <= MAX('Table'[Column1])
    ),
    'Table'[Column2]
)
```